# CSS - Realign content (remove white space) after transform: scale

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, css-transforms

So far I found only very complex or very "hacky" solution for the issue below:

What I have before transform

```css
.element1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.element2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2"></div>
</div>
```

What I get while I transform with scale:

```css
.element1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.element2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to get after transform: (this example does not contain transform, I just hardcoded widht/height, so its not solution)

```css
.element1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.element2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2"></div>
</div>
```

I have more dynamic website where additional content can be added and I still want to have it nicely aligned. A lot of solution is counting "height" somehow, but that I believe can brake easily when more items are added inside page.

Is there minimalistic approach to this example where we can in some clear way keep things aligned to each other after transform?

Comment: Why are you using a `transform` at all?

Comment: A `transform` is purely visual, it does not affect **actual** layout. You may have to rethink your approach.

Comment: Such transformations leave the original space the element would have occupied without the transformation, reserved - so there really isn't much you can do using CSS alone, this will need additional JS logic if you want to go that route.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Dobxgm

Comment: @Paulie_D - when mobile users are using the app, I need to "zoom them out" so they can read the elements properly. It actually works 100% as I need with two lines in css - beside that space below. I can use React as well if css is not enough.

Comment: There are other techniques to size elements more responsively than an arbitrary transform. A transform is not your optimal solution but demonstrating the actual issue rather than general examples would be ideal.

Comment: @Paulie_D - its actually amazing solution, that require minimum amount of work - in case you really want to resize everything including fonts etc.

Comment: Use media queries instead

Comment: @j08691 - can you be more specific? I am already using `@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)` which triggers some css styles to use `transform: scale(0.5)` and `transform-origin: top left;`. Which works great - except there is huge empty space on bottom after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by others there is no direct way how to do this properly in CSS.

It is recommended to use styles properly with annotation like `@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)` where you change the styles in a way its good experience on small devices.

However if you have limited time, the `scale` itself is working good enough for you for now - this is how I resolved it in React:

**PLEASE NOTE: This is very hacky solution with hardcoded values and altough it works, it is not recommended on production environment and especially not for any critical components you want to use.**

First I get reference to object that I am resizing with scale

```
import {useRef} from "react";
const dashboardTableRef = useRef(null);
...
<div ref={dashboardTableRef}>
```

Then I add function to count height dynamically in React and I add that style to the component that i need to resize in order to get-align again. (I scaling by 0.5, therefore I am diving height by 2)

```
    function countHeight() {
        if (dashboardTableRef.current?.offsetWidth > 700) {
            return "100%";
        }
        return "" + (dashboardTableRef?.current?.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    }
...
<div className="page-body" style={{height: countHeight()}}>
```

At the end on window resizing I am trigerring the re-rendering the React page by re-setting state (altough I had not changed anything there)

(as by default resizing window is not triggering react render, the browser is doing on its own)

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        setState({...state});
    });
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", () => {})
    }
}, []);
```